# How can I get a value of parameter in eventlistener?

Tags: javascript

How can I get value of `eventlistener(DOMContentLoaded)`

```js
getEventListeners(window).DOMContentLoaded[0].listener
```

That is my code, but I cannot get the parameter like `ecomm_productvalue`.  All I want to get is the "`customerBillingEmail`" value.

[image: event listenir code]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data-member of an object you have access to. Note that due to the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) the event is not being executed right-away, so the value will only be available once the event has successfully been executed. See:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    window.foo = "bar";
});

setTimeout(function() {console.log(window.foo);}, 100);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log(event); // THIS IS THE VALUE OF YOUR EVENT
});
```

Comment: there is a parametre like customerBillingEmail in exsis DomcontentLoaded ı just wanted to get value of the parametre. ı did not wanto create eventlistener

Comment: your parameter is inside a var named google_tag_params. Then just call it via google_tag_params.customerBillingEmail

Comment: but ı get error  every time , ı use that code getEventListeners(window).DOMContentLoaded[0].listener.google_tag_params("customerBillingEmail");
but ı get error like "Uncaught TypeError: getEventListeners(...).DOMContentLoaded[0].listener.google_tag_params is not a function
"

Comment: Try without getEventListeners(window).DOMContentLoaded[0].listener

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Ok then. You should be able to access google_tag_params variable anywhere in your code after the dom has loaded. Thats because var variables are attached at the topmost at the memory and can be then accessed everywhere. And that var has assigned inside the dom load callback